# ImportError: No module named bs4 using Canopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy, beautifulsoup

So I'm kinda new to this stuff but I was trying to learn about data scraping.  I was using some doc file online called "A beginner’s guide to data scraping in Python" and this was the code it told me to run:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bcsfootball.org').read())
for row in soup('table', {'class': 'mod-data'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string,tds[1].string
```

But when I ran it. I got

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I went around online and I tried installing BeautifulSoup4 using stuff like

Command Prompt:

```
easy_install BeautifulSoup4
```

And installing get-pip.py and running:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

(I used this after I tried the easy_install and it said something like requirement already satisfied so I'm guessing it was installed??)

Please help :(

Oh, Uhm I'm also using python 2.7.10

Comment: try upgrading it by pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4 . if doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are not installing the package into Canopy Python but rather into your system (or other) python. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line